# Batch file won't run as scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that creates a copy of an Access database as a backup and stores it on the network with a date stamp suffixed to the file name.  This batch file runs fine on its own and also as a scheduled task while I am logged into the server (Windows server 2008 R2).  But despite trying many things I cannot get the scheduled task to run when I am not logged into the server.  I have tried configuring the scheduled task properties to run with the highest privileges, tried switching the settings of "run whether user is logged in or not" - and sore password options,  tried amending the "Actions" tab by putting the path in the "Start In" parameter and only the batch file name in the "Program" parameter but still nothing works.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is find out whether the script isn't running _at all_, or just not being able to copy the file to the network location (I suspect the latter, as that usually needs network credentials).  If you haven't already got them, add `echo Script run on %DATE% at %TIME% > c:\users\USERNAME\Script.log` to the top of the script.  If the script _is_ running, it's to do with network credentials.  Assuming the script is running as a real user, I've sometimes found an explicit `net use x: \\server\sharename` helps (re)establish a connection.

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks.  I placed the echo line at the start of the batch file and then ran it first with me logged into the server and it created and updated the log - the first time.  I tried it again with me logged in and it did nothing.  I tried a third time with me logged out of the server and again it did nothing

Comment: First, I probably should have suggested `>>` instead of `>` in the above, so that it appends to the log each time instead of overwriting.  Second, if it really did nothing (i.e. the time in the log file didn't change from the first attempt) then it probably is to do with how scheduled tasks run [of which I've little experience].  If the time _did_ change, then it's to do with network permissions.

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks again.  I now have an entry in the log even if I am not logged into the server.  So must be a network permissions problem.  I will speak to the company infrastructure team and ask them to assist

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks so much.  I have it resolved.  If you create an answer I will mark it as accepted and score it

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I didn't provide an answer to your problem, only a way to go about isolating which bit wasn't working, leading you to solve it.  Depending on what the issue was, it might make sense for _you_ to edit the question to describe why the original didn't have network access and create an answer (self-answered questions are allowed) describing and what you did to fix it, as this may help others trying to run scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this resolved - you live and learn as they say - and I learned something about batch scripting that I wasn't aware of.  Thank you TripeHound for assisting me in pinpointing that it was a network issue.

My batch file was copying the Access database to my company's "I:\" drive, but I learned that while the user is NOT logged into the server the "I:\" drive is NOT recognized and so I changed the I:\ part to the actual server name path, i.e "\the_server\the_drive$" and then it all worked

Answer (score 0):

### Check with following script replace the the folder name with your network folder name. Disable the "Run only if logged on option" and store the password using "Set password" option.

@echo off 
set folderName=D:\omal\BackupProjectDaily\%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%
echo %folderName%
if not exist %folderName% md %folderName%
copy 1.txt %folderName%\1-%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~-4%.txt
pause

### exit